# How to load the contents in the text file or the html codes in a html-file to a textarea by browsing it first?

Tags: javascript, html

Using javascript, how to open a text-file or html-file from  a web-page and load the contents in the text file or the html code to a textarea. Please Dont tell me this not possible using javsscript, it is possible but i dont know the code and my bro not coming home for a week . Example codes will be greatly appreciated. (i have already asked this question but everyone seemed to concentrate on the other part of the question.)

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="abc">
<textarea name="text">loaded text here</textarea>
<input type="button" onClick=""> open file
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I found this in a forum , dont remember name , This is a working code but can only load text files .... now the question is how can I get it to fetch htmlcodes from a html file.

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">


<script type="text/javascript">

var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8;
var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

function loadFile(btn, obj, div, fld) {
objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
objStream = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading);
fld.value = objStream.ReadAll();
objStream.Close();
objStream= null;
fileSpecs(div, btn);
objFile = null;
return true;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">

<textarea rows="25" name="fileArea" cols="70"
onkeypress="return checkText(this, btnSave);"></textarea> </td>


<input type="file" name="fileName" size="50"
onchange="return checkFile(this, document.getElementById('fileSpec'), btnLoad, btnSave, fileArea);">

<input type="button" name="btnLoad" value="Load" 
onclick="return loadFile(this, fileName, document.getElementById('fileSpec'), fileArea);"> 

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is another one the coder claims it to be working but it is nt working for me , please execute this code if u hav time ...if it is working please provide the complete code here.
(coded by Ancora)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function init(){

var extText = window.frames.messageTxt.document.body.lastChild.lastChild.data;
extText = extText.replace(/[\r\n]/g," ");
document.forms[0].nMessage.value = extText;
}

window.onload=init;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name='messageTxt' src='txtData.txt'  style='display:none'></iframe>
<form>
<textarea name='nMessage'></textarea>
<input type="button" value="click" onClick="init()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i guess no can do this...i had a javascript that can load htmlcode form an external html file into the textarea. But i lost that file, sad no one here has the scripting abilities to create a js function (or active x) that can do the same.

Comment: it's not possible... just kidding.. :)

Comment: u have incorrect script, onclick="", any quotation marks inside must be escaped or remove the quotes around it... second: do you have a file called "ajax_json_echo" under root folder? and it should be server side page too...
tell you what, if you dont have a requirement for cross browser, this link works on IE only: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531417(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: thanx i need it to work in IE only (dont care about other browsers), and i dont hav ajax _json_echo file ..... so i am gona check the site now.

Comment: Looking for alternative answers tooo.... any suggestion will be welcomed

Comment: `$.get` and other code you're using looks like jQuery; you need to load the jQuery script: `<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: but if i want ajax then i must hav net , isnt it , besides i am asking a way to open files using javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open and save text in html to a file using javascript in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223915/how-to-open-and-save-text-in-html-to-a-file-using-javascript-in-html)

Comment: David , that post is also but all were only contrating on how to save the file , so i posted another one here

Comment: cmon some computer guru crack the code , i know u can . :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible, using AJAX.  You have to keep in mind that same-origin restrictions mean it will only work on your own domain.  One way is with [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

EDIT: A more complete demo (see also [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LApCF/2/)):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function download_to_textbox(url, el)
    {
      $.get(url, null, function(data)
                       {
                         el.val(data);
                       }, "text");
    }

    $(function()
    {
      $('#open').click(function()
      {
        download_to_textbox("/ajax_json_echo/?foo=bar", $("textarea[name='text']"));
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="abc">
        <textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="70">loaded text here</textarea>
        <input id="open" value="open" type="button">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the above code is that a function how do i call it using onclick command

Comment: You can also load the HTML document into a hidden iframe and then get the HTML from there. See http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3083765.htm

Comment: is my code correct ...plz rectify me if i am doing anything wrong

Comment: @subanki, if you have an inline event listener, you need to be sure you balance the quotes correctly.  It's cleaner to use a separate listener.  Also remember that the page must exist on the domain you're testing with.  Try this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LApCF/2/).

Comment: in that page y am i getting this as result

{"post_response": {}, "get_response": {"foo": "bar"}}

Comment: Thanx (A big one) i greatly appreciate your effort but by domain did u mean client computer .. the computer in which the script is being executed ... if yes then it still doesn't open up the "open dialog box"

Comment: @subanki, it's not supposed to open a dialog box.  Same domain/origin means roughly same webserver.  See [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  That is the output expected for the demo.  It is being echoed by the server.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I can get the inner-iframe thing working but I cannot yet undrestand the same origin policy thing, I got something loaded with my myWebSite.com but not with other site, cannot yet understand.

Comment: @hhh, as I said, this will only work on the same origin.  You can look into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) to try to get it working cross-domain.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: sorry this thread is broken and too cluttered, I opened a simplified q without clutter [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193300/replacing-hard-coded-values-in-textarea-with-file). I am not even sure whether we are speaking about the same issue because things are so dxmn cluttered.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above work fine but you have to understand what they're doing to customize.
Here is the simplest solution (customizing a solution stated above), it's
tested on IE8 and works fine (remember, you have to see the HTML render in your iframe to know that you got the `src` attribute correct):

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">   
function init(){ 
    var extText = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].outerHTML;
    document.getElementById("nMessage").innerText = extText;
} 

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <iframe name="messageTxt" src="[place the path to your html file here]" ></iframe> 
    <form> 
        <textarea name="nMessage" id="nMessage" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea> 
        <input type="button" value="click" onClick="init()" /> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: i am very noob at javascript, cant understand those sybols and characters easily, anyways thanx for the effort u took. i have already got what i wanted in an another post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235883/html-codes-from-external-html-file-in-to-textarea    

can u solve the last prob i have in that post . thanks again