# html codes from external html-file in to textarea (any professional in active-x or javascript help me)

Tags: javascript, html, activex

In the below code how can i make it load the file into a textarea where textarea path is parent.a.frame_name1.document.form_name1.textarea_name1

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Local File I/O</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- // Begin
var ForReading = 1,
    ForWriting = 2,
    ForAppending = 8;
var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

function checkText(fld, btn) {
    btn.disabled = false;
    fld.onkeypress = null;
    return true;
}

function checkFile(obj, div, btn, btn2, fld) {
    div.innerHTML = '<p><b>File:</b><br><b>Size:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Last Modified:</b></p>';
    btn.disabled = true;
    btn2.disabled = true;
    fld.value = '';
    fld.onkeypress = new Function("return checkText(" + "document." + fld.form.name + "." + fld.name + "," + "document." + btn2.form.name + "." + btn2.name + ")");
    //
    // if (obj.value.indexOf(":") != 1) {
    // alert("Local file name must include a drive letter.");
    // return false;
    // }
    var ary = obj.value.split("\\");
    if (ary.length < 2) {
        alert("Local file name must include a path.");
        return false;
    }
    if (!/(\.txt)$/i.test(obj.value)) {
        alert("Local file name must include the '.txt' extension.");
        return false;
    }
    //
    try {
        objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.message != "File not found") {
            alert(e.message);
            return false;
        } else {
            try {
                if (confirm(obj.value + "\n" + "does not exist. Click 'Ok' to create it.")) {
                    objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(obj.value);
                    objFile.Close();
                    objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    fileSpecs(div, btn);
    objFile = null;
    return true;
}

function fileSpecs(div, btn) {
    if (objFile.Size > 0) {
        btn.disabled = false;
    } else {
        btn.disabled = true;
    }
    var str = '<p>';
    str += '<b>File:</b> ' + objFile.Path + '<br>';
    str += '<b>Size:</b> ';
    if (objFile.Size < 1024) {
        str += objFile.Size + ' bytes';
    } else {
        str += (objFile.Size / 1024).toFixed(1) + ' Kbytes';
    }
    str += '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    str += '<b>Last Modified:</b> ' + objFile.DateLastModified;
    str += '</p>';
    div.innerHTML = str;
}

function loadFile(btn, obj, div, fld) {
    objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
    objStream = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading);
    fld.value = objStream.ReadAll();
    objStream.Close();
    objStream = null;
    fileSpecs(div, btn);
    objFile = null;
    return true;
}

function saveFile(btn, obj, div, fld, btn2) {
    btn.disabled = true;
    objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
    objStream = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting);
    objStream.Write(fld.value);
    objStream.Close();
    objStream = null;
    objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
    fileSpecs(div, btn2);
    objFile = null;
    fld.value = '';
    fld.onkeypress = new Function("return checkText(" + "document." + fld.form.name + "." + fld.name + "," + "document." + btn.form.name + "." + btn.name + ")");
    return true;
}
// End -->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
<table width="720">
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<div id="fileSpec">
<p><b>File:</b><br><b>Size:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Last Modified:</b></p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" width="580" align="center" valign="top">
<textarea rows="25" name="fileArea" cols="70"
onkeypress="return checkText(this, btnSave);"></textarea> </td>
<td rowspan="2" width="140" valign="top"><p>This is a simple demonstration of
a browser-based local text file editor.&nbsp; Begin by clicking the <b>Browse</b>
button to select an existing text file from your local hard drive.&nbsp;
(In the Browse dialog, you may type in a new file name if
desired.)&nbsp; The selected file information is then displayed at the
top of the page.&nbsp; For an existing file, click the <b>Load</b>
button next.&nbsp; After editing, click the <b>Save</b> button to
complete the demonstration.</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">
<input type="file" name="fileName" size="50"
onchange="return checkFile(this, document.getElementById('fileSpec'), btnLoad, btnSave, fileArea);"> </td>
<td align="center">
<input type="button" name="btnLoad" value="Load" disabled
onclick="return loadFile(this, fileName, document.getElementById('fileSpec'), fileArea);"> </td>
<td align="center">
<input type="button" name="btnSave" value="Save" disabled
onclick="return saveFile(this, fileName, document.getElementById('fileSpec'), fileArea, btnLoad);"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

(Also inform me whenever and what u have edited in my post , sad others coming and editing my post)

Comment: Your code is incomplete.
You need functions checkFile which takes a (hidden) input field with extensions and you need fileSpec function that does something to the buttons (like enable them). When I added empty functions for these, the file loaded - any text file including html

Comment: sorry for posting incomplete code

Comment: In the above code how can i make it load the file into a textarea where textarea path is parent.a.frame_name1.document.form_name1.textarea_name1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open and save text in html to a file using javascript in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223915/how-to-open-and-save-text-in-html-to-a-file-using-javascript-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the lines

```
    if (!/(\.txt)$/i.test(obj.value)) {
    alert("Local file name must include the '.txt' extension.");
    return false;
}
```

with

```
    if (!/(\.txt|\.htm|\.html)$/i.test(obj.value)) {
    alert("Local file name must include the '.txt', '.htm' or '.html' extension.");
    return false;
}
```

For your convenience, it now takes htm-files as well.

Comment: thanx frn , i will try executing it and inform you

Comment: Mr. AlbertVanHalen , the code works now , than you frnd , can you tell me your real name and form whihc country you are from .. so that i can include ur name in my creidt page .. plz post it here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236432/how-to-put-my-webpage-so-that-i-can-find-my-page-in-google-search

Comment: PS: You will find that may fail in IE8 since the file object no longer returns a real file path unless the security is lowered. I guess the security is already low in this case since you use the filesystem object to read the file

Comment: thanx friend , in the above code how can i make it load the file into a textarea where textarea path is 

parent.a.frame_name1.document.form_name1.textarea_name1