# how to put my webpage so that i can find my page in google search?

Tags: html

How to upload my webpage so that i can find my page in Google search?

Comment: klez how did u edit my post ???

Comment: klez has 2k+ reputation, he can edit (other peoples) posts because he has proven a valuable member of the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search engine optimization can be a time consuming process but there are several factors that go into it.

1. Your site should have good keyword rich page titles and URLs.
2. Your site should have keyword rich H1 tags on each page (only 1 H1 per page).
3. Each of your pages should have keyword rich content that is fluent.

Don't try to stuff keywords.

Also, your meta keywords should be separated by commas. No point in going over 45 characters, the big three won't read past that number. Your meta description should also be keyword rich and 1 - 2 sentences long.

Once your insite SEO is done then you can go to external sites and ask that they link back to your site using quality anchor text such as "Electric Motors" rather than "www.electricmotors.org".

Comment: wow a cool comment , thanx frnd , but how to put those meta..if it some code in the header, then plz provide that code

Comment: For the meta information, this code goes in the <head> of your document and should be on all pages, not just your home page. Each page should be optimized for what is on THAT page, not in your site as a whole. 

<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />

The keywords or description will be in the 'content=""' area inside the quotes.

Comment: W3Schools has this information on meta tags: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: thanx thanx thanx a lot ..hey i checked your profile there it says u know web-desgining , then assuming that u also know javascrpit can u help me here in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235883/html-codes-from-external-html-file-in-to-textarea-i-still-need-a-little-help-her

Comment: I actually don't write javascript. I'm sorry. But if I can help you with any more SEO I'd be happy to. =)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to put your web-page on a web-server that's publicly accessible ; you can find a lot of hosting services on the web *(if you only have a couple of simple pages, you won't need something that costs a lot)*.

Once the server is set up, you'll have to use something like an FTP Client *([FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is an example)*.

Then, you'll need the search engines to "know" your page -- best way is to have some other web-sites link to yours ; this way, crawlers will sooner or later discover your page.

Comment: isnt FTP used to transfer files online ??....also this is the same answer wat i gav in my class... But another student says it can also be done using meta tags that define some google stuff

Answer (score 0):

List of Best and Worst practices for designing a high traffic website:
http://www.webconfs.com/15-minute-seo.php

SEO Chat:
http://www.seochat.com/

Comment: wow useful links... thanks frnd

Comment: Those are both good references!