# how to load the text in another textarea where the textarea is within iframe

Tags: javascript, activex

in the below code plz tell me how to load the text in textarea where the textarea path is parent.frame_name1.iframe_name1.form_name1.textarea_name1

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Local File I/O</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- // Begin
    var ForReading = 1,
        ForWriting = 2,
        ForAppending = 8;
    var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    function checkText(fld, btn) {
        btn.disabled = false;
        fld.onkeypress = null;
        return true;
    }

    function checkFile(obj, div, btn, btn2, fld) {
        div.innerHTML = '<p><b>File:</b><br><b>Size:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Last Modified:</b></p>';
        btn.disabled = true;
        btn2.disabled = true;
        fld.value = '';
        fld.onkeypress = new Function("return checkText(" + "document." + fld.form.name + "." + fld.name + "," + "document." + btn2.form.name + "." + btn2.name + ")");
        //
        // if (obj.value.indexOf(":") != 1) {
        // alert("Local file name must include a drive letter.");
        // return false;
        // }
        var ary = obj.value.split("\\");
        if (ary.length < 2) {
            alert("Local file name must include a path.");
            return false;
        }
        if (!/(\.txt)$/i.test(obj.value)) {
            alert("Local file name must include the '.txt' extension.");
            return false;
        }
        //
        try {
            objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
        } catch (e) {
            if (e.message != "File not found") {
                alert(e.message);
                return false;
            } else {
                try {
                    if (confirm(obj.value + "\n" + "does not exist. Click 'Ok' to create it.")) {
                        objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(obj.value);
                        objFile.Close();
                        objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        fileSpecs(div, btn);
        objFile = null;
        return true;
    }

    function fileSpecs(div, btn) {
        if (objFile.Size > 0) {
            btn.disabled = false;
        } else {
            btn.disabled = true;
        }
        var str = '<p>';
        str += '<b>File:</b> ' + objFile.Path + '<br>';
        str += '<b>Size:</b> ';
        if (objFile.Size < 1024) {
            str += objFile.Size + ' bytes';
        } else {
            str += (objFile.Size / 1024).toFixed(1) + ' Kbytes';
        }
        str += '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        str += '<b>Last Modified:</b> ' + objFile.DateLastModified;
        str += '</p>';
        div.innerHTML = str;
    }

    function loadFile(btn, obj, div, fld) {
        objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
        objStream = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading);
        fld.value = objStream.ReadAll();
        objStream.Close();
        objStream = null;
        fileSpecs(div, btn);
        objFile = null;
        return true;
    }

    function saveFile(btn, obj, div, fld, btn2) {
        btn.disabled = true;
        objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
        objStream = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting);
        objStream.Write(fld.value);
        objStream.Close();
        objStream = null;
        objFile = objFSO.GetFile(obj.value);
        fileSpecs(div, btn2);
        objFile = null;
        fld.value = '';
        fld.onkeypress = new Function("return checkText(" + "document." + fld.form.name + "." + fld.name + "," + "document." + btn.form.name + "." + btn.name + ")");
        return true;
    }
    // End -->
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <center>
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <table width="720">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
    <div id="fileSpec">
    <p><b>File:</b><br><b>Size:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Last Modified:</b></p>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" width="580" align="center" valign="top">
    <textarea rows="25" name="fileArea" cols="70"
    onkeypress="return checkText(this, btnSave);"></textarea> </td>
    <td rowspan="2" width="140" valign="top"><p>This is a simple demonstration of
    a browser-based local text file editor.&nbsp; Begin by clicking the <b>Browse</b>
    button to select an existing text file from your local hard drive.&nbsp;
    (In the Browse dialog, you may type in a new file name if
    desired.)&nbsp; The selected file information is then displayed at the
    top of the page.&nbsp; For an existing file, click the <b>Load</b>
    button next.&nbsp; After editing, click the <b>Save</b> button to
    complete the demonstration.</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left">
    <input type="file" name="fileName" size="50"
    onchange="return checkFile(this, document.getElementById('fileSpec'), btnLoad, btnSave, fileArea);"> </td>
    <td align="center">
    <input type="button" name="btnLoad" value="Load" disabled
    onclick="return loadFile(this, fileName, document.getElementById('fileSpec'), fileArea);"> </td>
    <td align="center">
    <input type="button" name="btnSave" value="Save" disabled
    onclick="return saveFile(this, fileName, document.getElementById('fileSpec'), fileArea, btnLoad);"> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </center>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use "clean" words @ SO, please!

Comment: Spell correctly and stop using txtspeak and you might get some better responses.  And cursing at the community is not the right approach.

Comment: i am in a crisis and asking for help ...ppl only come and gv negative marking go...if u cant answer then go ..thats it

Comment: Please trim out the irrelevant code.

Comment: yodaj007 i really dont even understand a single line , if i had known i would hav done this long time ago

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235883/html-codes-from-external-html-file-in-to-textarea-any-proffessional-in-active-x

Comment: Tip: Don't accept an answer on the question if you aren't satisfied with the answer.  People see the accepted question and think it has been answered.  Next time, don't accept an answer unless it answers the question.  If it doesn't get answered, wait a few days, and then mark it with a bounty.

Comment: AlbertVanHalen were r u , u r the only one i know who can help me ...plz plz plz help me

Comment: also visit this post plz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236432/how-to-put-my-webpage-so-that-i-can-find-my-page-in-google-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you meaning that the filename what you want to load is contained in `parent.frame_name1.iframe_name1.form_name1.textarea_name1` ? In this case you should change the `<input type="file"/>` value dynamically, which is not supported by browsers (it would be a security issue).