# how to make the c compiler print \n

Tags: c

how to make the c compiler print \n

Comment: Do you mean how to create a c program that prints '\n' to output instead of inserting a new line?

Comment: The compiler, or the compiled program?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to do this?
printf("\n");

Comment: no i wanted to perform printf("\\n");
thnx ppl

Comment: Who on earth voted this question up? Or am I missing out on some bizarre joke? ;-)

Comment: Is this the kind of questions that get upvotes? I thought stackoverflow was for `professional and enthusiast programmers`. This guy didn't even take the time to write different subject and body!

Comment: @lacopo if i hav a doubt , i post it here, i dont even care abt votes , if i did i would hav first registered to this site....besides ...if u want a question that nobody answred till now then go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245039/how-to-load-the-text-in-another-textarea-where-the-textarea-is-within-iframe

Comment: As i know Compiler only compiles the program and does not print to the console.
Does it really prints to the console .?

Comment: That's why stackoverflow s**ks. N00b questions are voted up also the answers...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you mean the pair of characters, `\n`, as opposed to a newline character:

```
printf("\\n");
```

Answer (score 6):

Depends what you need.

Either:

```
printf("\\n"); /* prints \n */
```

or:

```
printf("\n");  /* prints newline */
```

Answer (score 5):

`printf("\\n");` [Escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw(VS.80).aspx) `\\` represents `\`

Comment: this place works like this :-) +1 for citing "escape sequence" the user should be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
#error "\\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\\n` to print `\n`

```
printf( "\\n"  );
```

> \n

Answer (score 0):

```
putchar('\\');
putchar('n');
```

Comment: still the user needs to know about escaping sequence... +1 because of alternative to printf.

Answer (score -1):

You can use escape char `\` `printf("\\n");`