# How to code this ActiveX function in PHP?

Tags: php, activex

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowFile(sFilePath){
    var oFileSystem = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    frmEditHTML.tarHTMLText.value = oFileSystem.OpenTextFile(sFilePath.value).ReadAll();
}

function SaveAfterEditing(sFilePath){
    var oFileSystem = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var oFile = oFileSystem.CreateTextFile(frmEditHTML.filPath.value,1);
    oFile.WriteLine(sFilePath.value);
    oFile.Close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmEditHTML">
Select the File you want to Edit
<input type=file name="filPath" onchange="ShowFile(this)">
<textarea name="tarHTMLText" cols=60 rows=20></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Save" name="cmdSave"  onclick="SaveAfterEditing(this.form['tarHTMLText'])">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223915/how-to-open-and-save-text-in-html-to-a-file-using-javascript-in-html) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226971/how-to-load-the-contents-in-the-text-file-or-the-html-codes-in-a-html-file-to-a) but they could not help!
I don't want to use ActiveX as then this function will be restricted to IE.
IE Tab in FireFox is also causes problems!
How can I replicate this whole function in PHP without using ActiveX ?
Please Help!

Comment: PHP runs on the server, while ActiveX runs on the client. This is impossible. Are you sure you know what PHP is?

Comment: You need to do it in javascript. But I'm not sure if browser will allow you do anything in file system.

Comment: @wormhit It won't, and if it did that would be a huge security hole. AFAIK, the closest the OP is going to get is to send a request to the server which then presents the user with a downloadable file.

Comment: Flash does allow you to save to a local file. You always get the save dialog box though. You can't save changes silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

With PHP you can't convert this script exactly as it is, since ActiveX is client side and PHP is server side. Javascript can't do this for you either, since modern browsers are sandboxed, and JavaScript cannot access local file systems.

---

### Not so short answer:

You have other options, however, depending on which behavior (and implementation method) you wish to mimic.

You can use a Java Applet that is able to do pretty much what you could do with ActiveX. Works consistently across browsers but user have to have installed Java Runtime Environment.

You can use a mix of PHP + Javascript (AJAX). You upload a file to the server and then control PHP actions with Javascript (HTTP Requests via Ajax).

---

### Hackish way

There is an hackish simple way to handle this situation. Requires a server somewhere though.

1. Create a page that uploads a file to the server.
2. Then send the file back to the browser, via AJAX (or any request, doesn't matter).
3. Manipulate the file in the client side (browser) with javascript.
4. Give the file to the user to download.

Comment: I will try this hackish way and see what result comes!