# Get source from HTML created by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple web form for teachers in my building to generate HTML pages with embedded videos to use locally (our substitutes can't get on the Internet to play videos; this is a workaround).

I'm using a script to take parameters from a form and dynamically build the HTML. I know the server is building the page, not the client, but is there no way for them to save the source?

I tried accessing the content with `document.getElementById('main').innerHTML`, but because there's no information in the DOM, it returns an error.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createNewWindow () {
  var userName = document.getElementById('user_name').value
  var videoSrc = document.getElementById('video_src').value
  var newPage = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css' /><title>"
  newPage += userName;
  newPage += "</title></head>";
  newPage += "<body><div id='main'><div id='content'><div class='video'>";
  newPage += "<video controls><source src='" + videoSrc;
  newPage += "' type='video/webm'/>";
  newPage += "</video></div <!--video-->>"
  newPage += "<input type='submit' value='Get Code' onclick='alert(document.getElementById(main).innerHTML);'"
  newPage += "</body></html>";
  var j = window.open('');
  j.document.write(newPage);
  j.document.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<p>
User name: <input type="text" id="user_name">
Video file: <input type="text" id="video_src">
<input type="submit"
  value="Create new page"
  onclick="createNewWindow();"
  >
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I first tried using `execCommand` to download the content, but running command-level scripts on school computers is blocked, so the solution [described in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223915/how-to-open-and-save-text-in-html-to-a-file-using-javascript-in-html) won't work for me.

I'm stuck on finding a simple way for non-programmers to save the generated page as HTML easily (avoiding Inspect Element, Firebug, etc). Any ideas?

Comment: `document.getElementById(\'main\').innerHTML` and no, they cannot themselves save the source on your server unless you allow them to send the html to your server

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open and save text in html to a file using javascript in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223915/how-to-open-and-save-text-in-html-to-a-file-using-javascript-in-html)

Comment: Seeing as how you're generating all the HTML in your JavaScript code, would an option be to also append the HTML into a `pre` element in the page which the user can easily copy from?

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong.you just want to display a form and after submitting the form it'll generate the HTML page ??

Comment: @Liam I think this is not a duplicate actually. The `window.open()`/`document.write()` approach in the code snippet here will work, and surprisingly none of the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223915/how-to-open-and-save-text-in-html-to-a-file-using-javascript-in-html even suggest using that. (afaict the problem in the OP’s code was just the quoting issue that @mplungjan noted.)

Comment: @Shrinath Yes, and that's the behavior now. I'm trying to get the HTML markup for someone who doesn't know how to inspect pages. I may use the text box mentioned by bunnmatt above rather than trying to get the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `newPage` already contains that html text, so you can create an html page, and save it instead of (or together with) opening a new window:

```js
function createNewWindow() {
    var userName = document.getElementById('user_name').value
    var videoSrc = document.getElementById('video_src').value
    var newPage = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css' /><title>"
    newPage += userName;
    newPage += "</title></head>";
    newPage += "<body><div id='main'><div id='content'><div class='video'>";
    newPage += "<video controls><source src='" + videoSrc;
    newPage += "' type='video/webm'/>";
    newPage += "</video></div <!--video-->>"
    newPage += "<input type='submit' value='Get Code' onclick='alert(document.getElementById(main).innerHTML);'"
    newPage += "</body></html>";

    var downlink = document.getElementById('downlink');
    downlink.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(newPage);

    var event = new MouseEvent('click');

    downlink.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```css
a {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <p>User name:
        <input type="text" id="user_name">Video file:
        <input type="text" id="video_src">
        <input type="button" id="createHtml" value="Create and download page" onclick="createNewWindow();">
    </p> 
  
    <a id="downlink" download="html_page.html"></a>

</form>
```

Comment: This is perfect...it was the route I was heading after reading last night, so I appreciate the worked solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the newly generated window to show you the HTML of the entire page, you need to use **onclick="document.body.parentNode.outerHTML"**, as this will get the whole HTML content taken from the *html* tag and within it.

Here's the corrected code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createNewWindow () {
  var userName = document.getElementById('user_name').value
  var videoSrc = document.getElementById('video_src').value
  var newPage = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css' /><title>"
  newPage += userName;
  newPage += "</title></head>";
  newPage += "<body><div id='main'><div id='content'><div class='video'>";
  newPage += "<video controls><source src='" + videoSrc;
  newPage += "' type='video/webm'/>";
  newPage += "</video></div <!--video-->>"
  newPage += "<input type='submit' value='Get Code' onclick='alert(document.body.parentNode.outerHTML)' />"
  newPage += "</body></html>";
  var j = window.open('');
  j.document.write(newPage);
  j.document.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<p>
User name: <input type="text" id="user_name">
Video file: <input type="text" id="video_src">
<input type="submit"
  value="Create new page"
  onclick="createNewWindow();"
  >
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you'd still like to extract only the content of the "main" element, you need to correct this line:

```
newPage += "<input type='submit' value='Get Code' onclick='alert(document.getElementById(main).innerHTML);'"
```

to this one:

```
 newPage += "<input type='submit' value='Get Code' onclick='alert(document.getElementById(\"main\").innerHTML);' />"
```